# Faster if statement evaluations in R

Tags: r, performance, if-statement

So I am trying to figure out if there is a better way to add multiple conditional statements to an if clause in `R` in order to speed up the process. Below is some code that I wrote that runs very fast on large datasets in the simple case and not so fast on the not so simple case.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!  Also, the tic-toc function is at the very bottom on the question in case you would like to run it yourself and see how fast the function runs.

Also, to give some intuition of what the code is doing, the first chunk is simply determining if there are any pairs of x's and y's that have larger values than all of the other x's and y's.

The second chunk of code is doing the same thing, however, it adds the condition that is any of the x values are actually equal to each other then check to see which one has the lowest y value.  Likewise, if any of the y values are equal to each other than check to see which one has the lowest x value.

So, running the code in the simple case I have the following:

```
tic()

x = runif(10000)
y = runif(10000)

front = 1:length(x)

for(i in 1:length(x)){
    for(n in 1:length(x)){
        if((x[i]>x[n]  &  y[i]>y[n])){
            front[i] = NA
            break
        }
    }
}

toc()
```

So as you can see, I am only evaluating the single condition that `x[i]>x[n]  &  y[i]>y[n]`

> toc()
>       elapsed 
>          1.28

and the code above runs in 1.28 seconds.
Now, running the code when I have three conditions to check I have the following:

```
tic()

x = runif(10000)
y = runif(10000)

front = 1:length(x)

for(i in 1:length(x)){
    for(n in 1:length(x)){
        if((x[i]>x[n]  &  y[i]>y[n]) | (x[i]==x[n] & y[i]!=min(y[which(x==x[i])])) | (y[i]==y[n] & x[i]!=min(x[which(y==y[i])]))){
            front[i] = NA
            break
        }
    }
}


toc()
```

so as you can see, I now have to check three conditions inside my if statement, namely,

```
(x[i]>x[n]  &  y[i]>y[n]) | (x[i]==x[n] & y[i]!=min(y[which(x==x[i])])) | (y[i]==y[n] & x[i]!=min(x[which(y==y[i])]))
```

however, this leads to a huge computational burden in `R` and make the code much more slow.

```
> toc()
elapsed 
  74.47
```

We see that running the newly adapted code its now slowed down considerably to 74.47 seconds. Now I am looking for either alternative function calls that would speed up my code or simply rewriting it in a "better" way that the code is not so slow.

Here is the code for the tic-toc function if needed:

```
tic <- function(gcFirst = TRUE, type=c("elapsed", "user.self", "sys.self"))
{
   type <- match.arg(type)
   assign(".type", type, envir=baseenv())
   if(gcFirst) gc(FALSE)
   tic <- proc.time()[type]         
   assign(".tic", tic, envir=baseenv())
   invisible(tic)
}

toc <- function()
{
   type <- get(".type", envir=baseenv())
   toc <- proc.time()[type]
   tic <- get(".tic", envir=baseenv())
   print(toc - tic)
   invisible(toc)
}
```

**EDIT for sashkello**

So my code now looks like this:

```
library(mvtnorm)
#Here are the variables I will be working with 

> x
 [1] 0.53137100 0.75357474 0.87904120 0.29727488 0.00000000 0.00000000
 [7] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.04059217
> y
 [1]  4.873500  3.896917  1.258215  5.776484 12.475491  5.273784 13.803158
 [8]  4.472204  2.629839  6.689242
> front
 [1] NA NA  3 NA NA NA NA NA  9 NA
> all.preds
[1] 0.596905183 0.027696850 1.005666896 0.007688514 3.900000000

    x = x[!is.na(front)]
    y = y[!is.na(front)]

    mu = c(all.preds[1],all.preds[3])
    sigma = matrix(c(all.preds[2],0,0,all.preds[4]),nrow=2)

    z = rmvnorm(10000,mu,sigma)
    z[,1] = sapply(z[,1],function(x){max(x,0)})

    points(z,col="black",pch=19,cex=.01)
    temp = 1:nrow(z)

    for(i in 1:length(temp)){
        cond1 = z[i,2]!=min(z[which(z[,1]==z[i,1]),2])
        cond2 = z[i,1]!=min(z[which(z[,2]==z[i,2]),1])
        for(n in 1:length(x)){
            if((z[i,1]>x[n]  &  z[i,2]>y[n]) | (z[i,1]==x[n] & cond1) | (z[i,2]==y[n] & cond2)){
                temp[i] = NA
                break
            }
        }
    }
    prop = sum(!is.na(temp))/length(temp)
```

and that cond1 and cond2 statement still take horribly long.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you could take the calculation of `cond1` and `cond2` out of the loop and calculate all `cond1[i]`/`cond2[i]` at once using `outer`.

Comment: @Roland, can you expand on that idea, and/or give a snippet of example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put `y[i]!=min(y[which(x==x[i])])` and `x[i]!=min(x[which(y==y[i])])` before the second loop, because they both only involve `i`.

```
for(i in 1:length(x)){
    cond1 = y[i]!=min(y[which(x==x[i])])
    cond2 = x[i]!=min(x[which(y==y[i])])
    for(n in 1:length(x)){
        if((x[i]>x[n]  &  y[i]>y[n]) | (x[i]==x[n] & cond1) | (y[i]==y[n] & cond2)){
```

This should speed things up significantly because both `min` and `which` are extremely slow and you are running them every time in the second loop.

Comment: Oh but I only want to evaluate the min and which statement when x[i]==x[n] or y[i]==y[n] so your suggestion won't work.

Comment: I'm tinkering with it as we speak.  The code I showed you was a small piece of a larger more complicated thing.  I'll keep you posted after I recode some stuff.

Comment: So in that bit of code it runs very fast, however, when I use it in my other code it still runs (unexpectedly) extremely slow.  Is there anyway I can show you the other part of my code and see if you have any suggestions?  Its basically the exact same code just with more "defined" data values.  I'll add an edit section above.

Comment: yeah, just copypaste it in the question. I don't know how much I can help, but won't hurt to eyeball it...

Comment: copy and paste is there in case you haven't seen it.

Comment: @StatMan I suggest you try to sort things. I'm not familiar with what you are trying to do, but I have a feeling you can cut your loops short if you know that your values are sorted. I think you can't sort them independently based on what I understand from your code, but you can sort, one of them and others accordingly...

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked for it, here is an efficient way to calculate `cond1` outside of a `for` loop (which you probably don't need at all):

```
#some data_
set.seed(42)
z <- matrix(sample(1:5, 200, TRUE), ncol=2)

#your loop
cond1 <- logical(100)

for (i in 1:100) {
cond1[i] = z[i,2]!=min(z[which(z[,1]==z[i,1]),2])
}

#alternative
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(z)
DT[, id:=.I]

DT[, cond1:=V2!=min(V2), by=V1]

#compare results
identical(DT[, cond1], cond1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: is there a way to do it using the outer command as you suggested before?

Comment: There might be. But it would still do a lot of unnecessary computations and need too much memory.

Comment: I am convinced that your data.table method works but is it possible to explain why? I read the help file but am still having a hard time understanding why it does work.

Comment: It's quite easy. For each unique value of column 1 (automatically named `V1`, but you could name the columns yourself) it calculates the minimum of the corresponding values in column 2 (`V2`) and compares each of these values with that minimum. The result of the comparison is assigned to a new column `cond1`. All of this is extremely efficient as (a) it is vectorized and (b) avoids objects being copied in memory.